# Combine calendars from Teams into a single calendar

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar, microsoft-teams

Is there a way to combine calendars from Teams 1-4 into a single calendar in the Mgmt Team?

Maybe inside of Teams for SharePoint?

[image: link to image below]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible using SharePoint OOTB web parts.

Using OOTB functionality, all you can do is: create a modern SharePoint page, add 4 [Group Calendar](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-group-calendar-web-part-eaf3c04d-5699-48cb-8b5e-3caa887d51ce) web parts on single page & show events from 4 teams in 4 web parts.

---

However, you can merge items from multiple calendars inside outlook, check below documentations:

1. [Merge items from multiple calendars](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/merge-items-from-multiple-calendars-0a7b4a55-ea17-4024-bc98-1766d2382780)
2. [View multiple calendars at the same time](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/view-multiple-calendars-at-the-same-time-fffa8783-0556-4ea1-ba62-3ed8a95a903c)

Now, you just need to find a way to add these merged calendars inside teams or SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not a current function.

As described on the following page:
[How to Merge Teams?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/microsoft-teams-how-to-merge-teams/7141c90d-c1d2-4dd3-80d3-4bbe23d7811a)

---

If the answer is helpful, please click "**√**" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: Is there any update on this thread? Comment here if you still need any help.